# Set a flexible container to the width and height of the image within without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I have a fluid layout with a central band of content consistning of a jQuery powered scroller from www.smoothdivscroll.com (similar to basic example here http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/basicDemo.htm).

Each box within the scroller consists of an image and text. The client wants each image to fill as much of the height of the scroller area as possible and each image will be a different size. The width of each image is therefore flexible. The width of the overall scroller is also flexible.

In the below example I can't work out why the size of the box is being pushed out to be much larger than the image within in cases where the image is very big (which they will have to be to scale on bigger browser windows). Actual image sizes are highlighted below. The one on the left is being upscaled while the one on the left is being downsized.

[image: flexible scroller]

The CSS I'm using is here: http://pastebin.com/uYT5ffR8

If I remove the height of the container for each grey box like so...

```
.smoothscroll .scroll-content-item { 
position: relative; float:left; margin:0 10px; padding:0; background:grey }
```

...the extra width disappears but of course the image within can't render the height: 100% property correctly (see below).

[image: flexible scroller 2]

I'm really stumped as to how I can achieve the layout required for each box with CSS.

Will I need to set a width on each image dynamically via JavaScript every time the browser is resized?

Comment: Can you put up a demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: Trying to get it working but seems to be failing for some reason.

Comment: Make sure you have all the JS files included. Post the URL and I will look.

Comment: FYI the scroller itself is fine it's purely the layout of the content within.

Comment: Afraid it's not live and I don't have a publicly accessible sharing space to hand. I'll see if I can find a way to get it online.

Comment: Or just edit your answer with the code. :)

Comment: @Steph let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2367/discussion-between-abraham-and-steph)

Answer (score 1):

1. Set image as DIV background and set height and width to 100% for that div. Image will be limited to original size.
2. Create div with `overflow:hidden` and put there image. It will be seen as much as possible for that div, and you will be able to set any for that image.